# MySql Query for prices with three or more decimal places

Tags: mysql, decimal

a customer has a database with all of his products (about 10k). Now he asked me to send him a list with all products which have a price with three or more decimal places (<--- I hope this is the right term. I mean all the numbers after the dot).

I can't think of a query which could to this. Any suggestions?

I am fairly new to MySql that's probably the main problem :-)

Thanks in advance!

Mark

PS: The customer doesn't want to have the numbers rounded - at least not now :-)

Comment: I'm afraid you have to use...MATH! <dramatic music...>

Comment: could you post some code?

Comment: @DonnieRock Yes, I can, see my answer.

Comment: @fancyPants my question was for Mark, I didn't see your comment when I asked it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark, try something like this.

```
SELECT field_name FROM table_name WHERE LENGTH(SUBSTR(column_name,INSTR(column_name,"."))) >3
```

Comment: This worked like a charm :-)

I only had to set it >3. With >2 it showed the .xx to

Thanks

Comment: I will update my answer as well, so that it will be helpful for other users as well.

Answer (score 0):

This solution also filters decimal places ending with `0`, i.e. `123.340` and `123.300` get filtered, as they are essentialy `123.34` and `123.3` respectively.

```
select 
your_column
from
your_table
where your_column * 100 - floor(your_column * 100) > 0
```

Comment: If I do it this way, I only get rounded results :-) Thanks anyway for your time!

Comment: @Mark That's just a "bonus" in my answer. `select * ...` or `select your_column ...` and you get of course your original column.

Comment: @Mark Was looking through old answers and found this. Added an explanation, why you might want to reconsider my answer.